# How to cross-compile Tensorflow-Lite for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to cross-compile Tensorflow-Lite for Raspberry Pi B+. To do that, I am following [these instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_rpi) from the official website, which are :

1. `git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools.git rpi_tools`
2. `git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git tensorflow_src`
3. `cd tensorflow_src && ./tensorflow/lite/tools/make/download_dependencies.sh`
4. `PATH=../rpi_tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin:$PATH \ ./tensorflow/lite/tools/make/build_rpi_lib.sh TARGET_ARCH=armv6` (step 4b for armv6, which should be the architecture of Raspberry Pi B+)

I tried to cross-compile on OSX 10.13 but the first step gave some conflicts because some files differ only for capital letters, (I am guessing) due to the case insensitiveness of OSX systems:

```
  'arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/include/linux/netfilter/xt_connmark.h'
  'arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/include/linux/netfilter/xt_DSCP.h'
  'arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/include/linux/netfilter/xt_dscp.h'
  'arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/include/linux/netfilter/xt_MARK.h'
  'arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/include/linux/netfilter/xt_mark.h'
  'arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/include/linux/netfilter/xt_RATEEST.h'
  'arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/include/linux/netfilter/xt_rateest.h'
  'arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/include/linux/netfilter/xt_TCPMSS.h'
  'arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/include/linux/netfilter/xt_tcpmss.h'
  'arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ECN.h'
  'arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ecn.h'
```

In turn, when trying to run step 4, I get this error:

```
make: *** [/Users/fra/Documents/TFLiteComp4RPi/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/rpi_armv6/obj/tensorflow/lite/core/api/flatbuffer_conversions.o] Error 126
/bin/bash: ../rpi_tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: cannot execute binary file
make: *** [/Users/fra/Documents/TFLiteComp4RPi/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/rpi_armv6/obj/tensorflow/lite/core/api/op_resolver.o] Error 126
/bin/bash: ../rpi_tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: cannot execute binary file
make: *** [/Users/fra/Documents/TFLiteComp4RPi/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/rpi_armv6/obj/tensorflow/lite/core/subgraph.o] Error 126
/bin/bash: ../rpi_tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: cannot execute binary file
make: *** [/Users/fra/Documents/TFLiteComp4RPi/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/rpi_armv6/obj/tensorflow/lite/core/api/tensor_utils.o] Error 126
/bin/bash: ../rpi_tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: cannot execute binary file
make: *** [/Users/fra/Documents/TFLiteComp4RPi/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/rpi_armv6/obj/tensorflow/lite/core/api/error_reporter.o] Error 126
/bin/bash: ../rpi_tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: cannot execute binary file
make: *** [/Users/fra/Documents/TFLiteComp4RPi/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/rpi_armv6/obj/tensorflow/lite/experimental/resource/resource_variable.o] Error 126
/bin/bash: ../rpi_tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: cannot execute binary file
make: *** [/Users/fra/Documents/TFLiteComp4RPi/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/rpi_armv6/obj/tensorflow/lite/c/c_api_experimental.o] Error 126
/bin/bash: ../rpi_tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: cannot execute binary file
make: *** [/Users/fra/Documents/TFLiteComp4RPi/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/rpi_armv6/obj/tensorflow/lite/allocation.o] Error 126
```

I tried to compile also on Ubuntu 18.04, however the 4th step gave me errors. The error output is quite long but looks like this

> /home/fra/Documents/TFLiteBuild4RPi/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/downloads/ruy/ruy/create_trmul_params.h:
> In function 'void ruy::detail::FinalizeMulParams(const
> ruy::MulParams<AccumScalar, DstScalar>&, ruy::ChannelDimension,
> ruy::Ctx*, ruy::TrMulParams*)':
> /home/fra/Documents/TFLiteBuild4RPi/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/downloads/ruy/ruy/create_trmul_params.h:388:17:
> error: 'is_trivially_copyable' is not a member of 'std'
> static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable::value, "");
> ^ /home/fra/Documents/TFLiteBuild4RPi/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/downloads/ruy/ruy/create_trmul_params.h:388:57:
> error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
> static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable::value, "");
> ^ /home/fra/Documents/TFLiteBuild4RPi/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/downloads/ruy/ruy/create_trmul_params.h:388:58:
> error: '::value' has not been declared
> static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable::value, "");
>
> ........................
> [/home/fra/Documents/TFLiteBuild4RPi/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/rpi_armv6/obj/tensorflow/lite/kernels/gather.o]
> Error 1 tensorflow/lite/tools/make/Makefile:333: recipe for target
> '/home/fra/Documents/TFLiteBuild4RPi/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/rpi_armv6/obj/tensorflow/lite/kernels/activations.o'
> failed make: ***
> [/home/fra/Documents/TFLiteBuild4RPi/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/rpi_armv6/obj/tensorflow/lite/kernels/activations.o]
> Error 1 tensorflow/lite/tools/make/Makefile:333: recipe for target
> '/home/fra/Documents/TFLiteBuild4RPi/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/rpi_armv6/obj/tensorflow/lite/kernels/mfcc.o'
> failed make: ***
> [/home/fra/Documents/TFLiteBuild4RPi/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/rpi_armv6/obj/tensorflow/lite/kernels/mfcc.o]
> Error 1 tensorflow/lite/tools/make/Makefile:333: recipe for target
> '/home/fra/Documents/TFLiteBuild4RPi/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/rpi_armv6/obj/tensorflow/lite/kernels/cumsum.o'
> failed make: ***
> [/home/fra/Documents/TFLiteBuild4RPi/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/rpi_armv6/obj/tensorflow/lite/kernels/cumsum.o]
> Error 1 tensorflow/lite/tools/make/Makefile:333: recipe for target
> '/home/fra/Documents/TFLiteBuild4RPi/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/rpi_armv6/obj/tensorflow/lite/kernels/conv.o'
> failed make: ***
> [/home/fra/Documents/TFLiteBuild4RPi/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/rpi_armv6/obj/tensorflow/lite/kernels/conv.o]
> Error 1 make: Leaving directory
> '/home/fra/Documents/TFLiteBuild4RPi/tensorflow_src'

**UPDATE**

I also did `docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:latest`, launch the docker image and do the same commmands but still there are errors even if the page said it was tested on that docker image.

Comment: I'm have exactly the same issue. Any possibility you've solved this since your post?

Comment: Nope, for the moment I gave up waiting an answer here but it seems to me TF questions are not very popular.

Comment: I was able to get past that using Ubuntu by using apt to install arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ directly. I then ran /tensorflow/lite/tools/make/build_rpi_lib.sh TARGET_ARCH=arm. That did seem to compile but I was unable to get the python wheel to honor the architectureon no matter what I tried. I still haven't been able to link the tensorflow-lite.a yet b/c I just realized the g++ complier I used couldn't even produce a minimal binary for the zero. So I installed arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ which is producing binaries that actually work for the zero. I'll report back if I get any traction

Comment: Okay I was able to get it compiled. Sorry for the github link but guessing that's the best way to distribute the .a file: https://github.com/aldenprudent/pizero-tflite. Unfortunately I'm having trouble linking the C++ minimal tflite example. Will keep hacking on it :-/

Answer (score 0):

For 32-bit build:

1. Check architecture for Raspberry Pi B+.
   $ lscpu
   OR
   $ uname -a
2. PATH=../rpi_tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-rpi-4.9.3-linux-gnueabihf/bin:$PATH 
   ./tensorflow/lite/tools/make/build_rpi_lib.sh TARGET_ARCH=(Specify architecture of your TARGET i.e  Raspberry Pi B+)

For 64-bit build:
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_arm64